# Управление проектом

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Занимался тем, что временно исключал из проекта некоторые файлы, случайно ткнул в пункт Generated Sources Root, теперь не могу эту задачу скомпилировать.
Как вернуть к начальному состоянию? Удаление и новое скачивание с сервера проблему оставляет нерешенной.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Благодарю пользователя [komdosh](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/184435/komdosh) за комментарий, с его помощью разобрался.

Comment: попробуйте sources root выбрать.

Comment: Естественно, я перепробовал все варианты, какие мог, в варианте sources root не видит основной класс поддиректорий, сейчас попробую добавить другой скрин в основной вопрос. Собственно, папка home01 помечена каким то синим квадратиком, проблема, видимо, в нем, но что он означает?

Comment: Квадратик означает модуль, покажите окно projectStructure, его можно вызвать комбинацией ctrl+alt+shift+s

Answer (score 0):

Правой кнопкой мыши выберите папу в навигаторе проекта, которую вы пометили как `Generated Sources Root`, затем выберите из меню `Unmark as Sources Root`.